# Problem with mongooseim inbox and chat marker

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, mongoose-im

I want to send two markers to the sender and have a problem with mongoose-im inbox.

1. Received marker
2. Displayed marker

I want to reset the inbox-counter (unread-count) with displayed marker,
but when I send the received-marker (or any message stanza) the counter will be reset and last message-id will change to marker-id (stanza id). 
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In `mod_inbox` configuration you can pass option `reset_markers` which provides the list of markers that will reset the counter. However it works for a receiver of the message. 
Any message send by sender will reset his counter, as there is silent assumption that if you post a message, it means that you've read all the previous.

Check out the docs:
https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_inbox/